# Identify if array in object. Php

Tags: php, arrays, object

Working against an API for an accounting system and wondering how to handle the return of fiscals years. I want to iterate each fiscal year, which is no problem if there are multiple fiscal years. However if there is only one fiscal year the returned object/array is slightly different, how should I handle this, ie how to identify the subarray?

//Example data if multiple fiscal years

```
stdClass Object
(
    [GetFiscalYearsResult] => stdClass Object
        (
            [FiscalYear] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [Id] => 257c2e5e-2b5b-4eea-9405-775caef357d4
                            [StartingDate] => 2015-01-01T00:00:00Z
                            [EndingDate] => 2016-01-01T00:00:00Z
                            [IsLocked] => 
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [Id] => 376ce224-77ce-43cd-b3c4-a3703b1fc8bf
                            [StartingDate] => 2018-01-01T00:00:00Z
                            [EndingDate] => 2019-01-01T00:00:00Z
                            [IsLocked] => 
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

//Example data if one fiscal year

```
stdClass Object
(
    [GetFiscalYearsResult] => stdClass Object
        (
            [FiscalYear] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => f2712737-9c63-4c4b-b107-1b841985cffb
                    [StartingDate] => 2019-01-01T00:00:00Z
                    [EndingDate] => 2020-01-01T00:00:00Z
                    [IsLocked] => 
                )
        )
)
```

//Current php code for multiple fiscal years

```
$Result = $Service->GetFiscalYears();
    foreach($Result->GetFiscalYearsResult->FiscalYear as $item=>$object) {
    $YE = date('Y-m-d',(strtotime ( '-1 day' , strtotime ( $object -> EndingDate) ) )); 
    echo $YE 
}
```

//EDIT With solution (identification of subarray with is_array)

```
          $Result = $Service->GetFiscalYears();
          if(is_array($Result->GetFiscalYearsResult->FiscalYear)){ 
              foreach($Result->GetFiscalYearsResult->FiscalYear as $item=>$object) {
                 CODE 
              } 
          } else { //if only one fiscal year
CODE
          }
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to check if it is an array using [is_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php)?

Comment: @Thefourthbird, could be a solution, will try it

Comment: found a solution with is_array, posted above. Thanks!